# why this bootstrap code is not working for nested rows?

Tags: bootstrap-4

This is my code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <title></title>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-3">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 newDive">
                            lefft 1
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 newDive">
                            left 2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="newDive">
                        right
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My expected outcome is as shown:

[image]

But I'm getting output as the right column height is upto left 1. it is not filled completely upto left 2, why?

I'm new to bootstrap and started learning today only.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing div to close your first row just above the container closing div near the bottom. Here is the code with the div added. I also recopied the bootstrap 4.4.1 cdn just in case there was a spelling error in the sample below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
    </head>

    <title></title>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 newDive">
                            lefft 1
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 newDive">
                            left 2
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="newDive">
                        right
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: still getting same result

Comment: I tested the code as a stand alone html page using google chrome and it works perfectly. It sounds like their might be some other environment variable cause the problem. What are you working in handlebars, angular, etc.?